# Django CharField blank vs default empty

Tags: python, django, django-models

What is the difference between this two fields in a Django app? What behaviour should I expect?

```
field_a = CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='field_a', blank=True)
field_b = CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='field_b', blank=True, default='')
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If `default` value is not given, empty string is used for `CharField` according to the following code (taken from `django/db/models/fields/__init__.py` [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.9.x/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L791)):

```
def get_default(self):
    """
    Returns the default value for this field.
    """
    if self.has_default():
        if callable(self.default):
            return self.default()
        return self.default
    if (not self.empty_strings_allowed or (self.null and
               not connection.features.interprets_empty_strings_as_nulls)):
        return None
    return ""
```

So they should behave same.

Comment: This. Best practice for general text-based fields (`CharField`, `TextField`.etc) is to use `CharField(blank=True)`. Do NOT use `CharField(null=True)`.

Comment: I see, but if I remove the default="" from field_b django generates a migration. Can you explain why?

Comment: @Kye, I don't get why you mentioned about `null=True`.

Comment: Django generates a migration whenever you change any arguments on a field definition, regardless of whether or not it has an effect on the database.

@falsetru: wasn't against your response, just a general related tip as OP didn't seem to have a firm grasp on the area.